# Python Socket Connection

Tags: python, sockets

I want to connect computers what is not in my lan. I want to connect real ip.

My server Code

```
import json
import os
import select
import socket
import sys
import urllib
import urllib.request
from optparse import OptionParser

ip = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip').read().decode("utf-8"))['origin']
print(ip)


def isAlive(ip):
    ret = os.system("ping -o -c 3 -W 3000 " + ip)
    if ret != 0:
        return True
    return False


HOST = socket.gethostname()

SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 1024
PORT = 1993

def chat_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.listen(10)

    # add server socket object to the list of readable connections
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print("Chat server started on port " + str(PORT), "on Host " + str(HOST))
    print(SOCKET_LIST)
    while True:
        ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST, [], [], 0)

        for sock in ready_to_read:
            if sock == server_socket:
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print("Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr)
                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)
            else:
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    recvString = data.decode("utf-8")
                    print(recvString)
                    if data:
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)
                    else:
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()


def broadcast(server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock:
            try:
                socket.send(message)
            except:
                socket.close()
                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

Connection Code

```
import socket

print(socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP))
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket successfully created")
    print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
except socket.error as err:
    print("socket creation failed with error %s" % (err))

port = 1993
host_ip = '193.140.109.2'
s.connect((host_ip, port))

while True:
    getGet = input("Send Data: ")
    s.sendall(bytearray(getGet, 'utf8'))

    if getGet == '-':
        s.close()
```

I wrote this code but I cannot connect my pc. I have some questions.
1- Is sockets only for lan connection ?
2- How can i connect diffrent computer ?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what sockets are and how they are used. Perhaps you should do some [further reading on sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) and a [Python networking tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) first.

Comment: Thank you for you comment but i already saw this link. And this link does not show me how to connect nonlocal pc

Comment: That's kind of my point. You're looking for a tutorial on how to do X, but you're missing the underlying concepts that explain why it's difficult to do so. The server has to be actually listening on the port you've given for a socket connection. You certainly can use sockets over the internet, but HTTPS would probably be more appropriate. Do you control the server you're connecting to? Are you sure it's listening for the socket connection? What happened when you ran this script? If you got exceptions, add the complete traceback to your question.

Comment: Also take a look at [socket.getaddrinfo()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo). That might help you get the connection parameters you need to connect to your target.

Comment: Yes, server is mine and i wrote script for it too. Now my server is online and listening but i cannot reach it.
TCP    10.5.43.120:1993       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: Can you connect to it with any other means? FTP? Ping? Are there firewalls or proxies between them that could be intercepting your connection?

Comment: No problem with ftp putty FZ. Only problem with script

Comment: You should probably try using a different tool like netcat or SocketSniff to see if you can connect to the socket with something besides your script. That will tell you if the problem is with your script or the socket connection itself.

Comment: I will thanks a lot :)

Comment: Either way though, you should definitely add more information to this question. Describe exactly what you observed when you ran the script, and how it differed from what you expected. Without those details, your question could be closed for not provided a clear description of your problem.

Comment: i solved my problem with ipv6 thanks

Comment: You should add an answer to this question. Show the code you've changed and try to explain why it fixes your issue. SO encourages answering your own question once you find a solution. You can accept your own answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
port = 1993
host_ip = 'fe80::d862:a887:2f4c:53d0%12'
```

Solved my problem.